# use function keys to locate particular control in vb.net window application

Tags: vb.net, winforms

my vb.net application i have one toolstrip menu.while clicking tool strip.i am opening four fourms at a time..this all are my child forums.so i given code in 
InvolveAllToolStripMenuItem_Click:

```
Private Sub InvolveAllToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles InvolveAllToolStripMenuItem.Click
    AddHandler Me.KeyUp, AddressOf HandleKeyPress
    Dim frm As New frmKeyAssignBoard
    frm.Location = New Point(625, 0)
    frm.MdiParent = Me
    AddHandler frm.KeyUp, AddressOf HandleKeyPress
    frm.Show()
    Dim frm1 As New FrmrecievedDelivaryRequest
    frm1.Location = New Point(625, 225)
    frm1.MdiParent = Me
    AddHandler frm.KeyUp, AddressOf HandleKeyPress
    frm1.Show()
    Dim frm2 As New FrmDelivary
    frm2.Location = New Point(965, 0)
    frm2.MdiParent = Me
    AddHandler frm.KeyUp, AddressOf HandleKeyPress
    frm2.Show()
    Dim frm3 As New frmCarCall
    frm3.Location = New Point(0, 0)
    frm3.MdiParent = Me
    AddHandler frm.KeyUp, AddressOf HandleKeyPress
    frm3.Show()
End Sub
```

I want to set some function keys here:

- If i click f3, i want to locate cursor to particular textbox inside the frmKeyAssignBoard.
- If i click f4, i want to locate cursor to particular textbox inside the FrmrecievedDelivaryRequest.

So where i can write program for this ?

Comment: you mean "push F3" .... Try it in your MDI parent keydown event ...

Answer (score 0):

To capture the key press event, normally we handle form's KeyPress or KeyUp event.

however at your case, you got 5 forms open (parent + 4 children). thus i would suggest you write the handler in the parent form, but register all children's keypress event to it, some pseudocode:

> ```
>     Sub ShowChildren()
>         ' Handle own Key up event
>         AddHandler Me.KeyUp, AddressOf HandleKeyPress
>
>         ' form 1
>         Dim frm As New frmKeyAssignBoard()
>         frm.Location = New Point(625, 0)
>         frm.MdiParent = Me
>         AddHandler frm.KeyUp, AddressOf HandleKeyPress
>
>         ' similar for frm2, frm3, ...
>         ' 
>     End Sub
>
>     Private Sub HandleKeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
>         If e.KeyCode = Keys.F2 Then
>             ' do whatever necessary when F2 is pressed
>         ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.F3 Then
>             ' do whatever necessary when F3 is pressed
>             ' for example, if you want fo focus on frm1's particular control
>             '         but have to expose TxtBox as a public readonly property beforehand
>             frm1.BringToFront()
>             frm1.TxtBox.Select()
>             frm1.TxtBox.Focus()
>         ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.F4 Then
>             ' do whatever necessary when F4 is pressed
>         Else
>             '...
>         End If
>     End Sub
> ```

Comment: sir,,i will check and let u know

Comment: while giving this(AddressOf HandleKeyPress ) getting error:HandleKeyPress  is not declared,it may be inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: where did you call addhandler frm.KeyUp, addressof handleKeyPress?  isn't it in the same form/class?

Comment: it normally works if you write them properly... if you want ppl to help you debug, pls post them up.

Comment: what ever you said like that i created one subprogram in same form  Sub ShowChildren(),inside this i try to call that ,,but showing error

Comment: i don't know where you put the HandleKeyPress method and the protection level of it, neither do I know how you define/structure your code. last suggestion i can think for your case - define your handler as an anonymous method within the caller and that will be definitely accessible within the method.

Comment: where i can get HandleKeyPress event